# Xamarin tutorial, Google OAuth authorization error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Following the Xamarin tutorial [Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/) instead of the Google login page, I'm getting

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. The redirect URI in the request,
>   http://blank.org, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth
>   client

In my Google Developers Console, API Manager, Credentials, Web Client 1, Authorized redirect URIs I have included "http://blank.org". Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Did you give it some time to propagate? It can take some time for changes in the Google Developer's Console to go live.

Comment: Tested again today with same result

Comment: I've managed to reach the Google login page by setting redirectUrl to a valid website, but one which has no connection whatsoever with the Xamarin forms app. It is a url which is stored in my Google developer console and works with an MVC app. What I don't understand is how to set a Google redirectUrl that points to an android mobile device. Or is it not required? Is any valid website address simply good enough?